# CSS thumbnail align

Tags: css, gallery, thumbnails

I made a small gallery to show a couple thumbnails. I got it to automatically fill any available space with a thumbnail so it works when resizing. 
The issue is that the thumbnails dont stay centered, there's a trailing excess space on the right when resizing. Ive tried many combinations of margins, padding, alignments, and more to try and get it centered for the row that its on, and none are able to work so far.

here is the page:
http://segnosis.net/demo.html

This is the relevant css:

```
/*contains all the thumbnail items*/
.thumbcontainer
{

}

/*thumbnail image container*/
.galleryitem
{
width:150px;
height:200px;
margin-left:20px;
margin-right:20px;
float:left;
}

.thumbname
{
text-align:center;
color:#2C3635;
font-family:verdana,sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
line-height:14px;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, in your .barbody css you cannot use `width: 100% - 1px;` I am posting your solution momentarily.

Comment: alrighty, I set it to - 1 to correct the border offset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `display: inline-block` instead of `float:left` can solve the problem. Set your `.thumbcontainer` to `text-align:center` and swap the float role on `.galleryitem` with `display:inline-block`, like so:

```
/*contains all the thumbnail items*/
.thumbcontainer
{
text-align:center;
}

/*thumbnail image container*/
.galleryitem
{
width:150px;
height:200px;
margin-left:20px;
margin-right:20px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Inline-block is [not supported very well by IE 6/7](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html), but if that's not a problem this solution will work nicely in all other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Add a "text-align: center;" to your .galleryitem rule

You've got the images as inline items which means they basically behave like text.

Comment: This doesn't fully solve the problem, there is still leftover space on the right side.

Comment: I have tried that before, I added it in, as you can see it changes nothing for the images